# Python won't convert tuple to string

Tags: python, string, tuples

so the below code is supposed to take the first element in the resulting tuple of x and convert it to a string to be used. However, when executing the last line it tells me it can't convert from tuple to str.

```
for x in filelink:
            print(x[0])
            item = str(x[0])
            oldpath = root.wgetdir + "\\" + root.website.get() + "\\" + item
            print(oldpath)
            if os.path.exists(oldpath): shutil.copy(root.wgetdir + "\\" + root.website.get() + "\\" + x, keyworddir + "\\" + item)
```

Comment: `x, keyworddir` creates a tuple and you are trying to concatenate that with a string.

Comment: @thefourtheye: No, that's the comma between function arguments.

Comment: Can't really tell because you haven't posted what `filelink` is or the exact exception you are receiving, but it sounds like x[0] is itself a tuple.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh, You are correct :) +1

Comment: @Kyle: Don't concatenate file paths manually. Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
root.wgetdir + "\\" + root.website.get() + "\\" + x
                                       right here ^
```

is using the tuple instead of `item`.